# How does Spring deal with @Autowired on fields that required a parameter? In this case, JdbcTemplate with DataSource

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jdbc

I have a SpringBoot app that I want to connect to my MySQL database and I want to connect it with JDBC (by itself, not using JPA). And from what I have seen on articles, one way to achieve this is with `JdbcTemplate` and `DataSource` objects).

Now I have a `RestController` where I call my database, "CoffeeShop" which has me with the following class/code:

```
@RestController
public class MenuController {
    
    
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private String menuQuery = "SELECT * FROM menu";

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    @GetMapping(path="/menu")
    public String getMenu(){

        jdbcTemplate.query(menuQuery, (rs, rowNum) -> new Menu(rs.getString("name"))).forEach(
            customer-> System.out.println(customer.getName()));

        return  "worked";
    }

    private List<Menu> organizeMenu() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

If my understanding is correct, I expect that  `dataSource` will be able to see in my `application.properties` file the following contents when being compiled and then Spring figures out that `jdbcTemplate` requires it?:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.driverclassname = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/CoffeeShop?useUnicode=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
```

To my surprise this worked, my code queried the DB and logged the correct output. But I'm not sure how this worked since `jdbcTemplate` required `dataSource`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the Spring Boot [Getting Started | Accessing Relational Data using JDBC with Spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/) guide, which says:

> Spring Boot supports H2 (an in-memory relational database engine) and automatically creates a connection. **Because we use `spring-jdbc`, Spring Boot automatically creates a `JdbcTemplate`.** The `@Autowired JdbcTemplate` field automatically loads it and makes it available.

This is what you get with the auto-configuration provided by Spring Boot: Fully functional `JdbcTemplate` automatically created and configured from the `application.properties` file.

---

*FYI:* The `JdbcTemplate` is already configured to use the `DataSource`, so you don't need to auto-wire the `DataSource`. As you can see in your own code, the `dataSource` field isn't used anywhere, so you should remove it.

It is actually the `DataSource` that is auto-configured from the `application.properties` file.